# "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" trying to read json

Tags: python, json

I was trying to read the 30 first comments from a `json` format with this code is what wrote:

```
list_of_comments=list()
while (j<30):          
        list_of_comments.append((talkbacks["data"]["list"][j]["content"],talkbacks["data"]["list"][j] 
        ["positive"],talkbacks["data"]["list"][j]["negative"]))
```

when i run this code it gives me the "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" error. I cant see what im missing here, probably something with the dict/list locations. please save me

this is my json:

```
{'result': 'success', 'data': {'list': [{'id': 45969880, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'מגלה שקרנים ', 'content': 'חחחחחחח עוד100שמנ חחחחחחחחחחחחחחחח תפי על אבא שלכם', 'createDate': '23:20 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 23:20:09', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45965215, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'וואלה', 'content': 'מה שלא יכחד לעולם זה "המומחים המזהירים"', 'createDate': '15:24 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 15:24:37', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45965179, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'נו', 'content': 'אולי הדובים הלבנים יעלמו אבל מה שלא יכחד לעולם אלה הפילים הלבנים של ממשלות ישראל.', 'createDate': '15:20 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 15:20:57', 'positive': 1, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45958898, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': '.', 'content': 'אל תאמינו למומחים כי הם לא מומחים\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nחרטא\n\n\n', 'createDate': '06:28 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 06:28:43', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45958450, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'בני האדם', 'content': 'העיקר שהחיה שהכי מסוכנת בעולם לא תיכחד', 'createDate': '03:08 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 03:08:20', 'positive': 1, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45958360, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'דובי', 'content': 'המומחים ייכחדו הרבה לפנינו...אז שלא "ידאגו" לנו !', 'createDate': '02:13 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 02:13:54', 'positive': 2, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45958315, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'ש', 'content': 'נקווה שהאדם ייכחד קצת קודם', 'createDate': '01:59 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 01:59:30', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45958030, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': ' רפואה משלימה', 'content': 'אביגדור ליברמן: אז עם מי יקים גנץ קואליציה ?', 'createDate': '00:45 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 00:45:15', 'positive': 1, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45958012, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'אל דאגה', 'content': 'עד אז החוקרים ייכחדו לפניהם', 'createDate': '00:40 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 00:40:34', 'positive': 2, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45957755, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'רוני', 'content': 'דוקטור תציל אותי אני מאוהב תתעוררוחחחחח', 'createDate': '23:59 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 23:59:39', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45957754, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'טלי', 'content': 'לא נורא יש לנו את שמחה גואטה מקסימום נישלח אותה לאנטראטיקה תעשה תצוגות אופנה לדאבות זן חדש במקום דובי קוטב דאבות', 'createDate': '23:59 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 23:59:39', 'positive': 2, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45957607, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'תבדקו או תנחשו', 'content': 'לא הבנתי את מי המזהירים המומחים הללו?\nאותי? אותך?\nמליוני זנים, כם דל בני אדם, נכחדו בעולם הזה ואחרים צצו. מה יש להזהיר פה ואת מי?', 'createDate': '23:38 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 23:38:47', 'positive': 1, 'negative': 1, 'children': []}, {'id': 45957194, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'גוגו', 'content': 'מתי יכחדו מרוקאים. "ביביסטים".?', 'createDate': '22:57 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:57:56', 'positive': 3, 'negative': 4, 'children': [{'id': 45957295, 'fatherId': 45957194, 'writer': 'מיקי', 'content': 'לא יקרה, אותנו אי אפשר להעמיס לקרונות רכבת...אתם רגילים ללכת כצאן לטבח אנחנו פחות בנויים לזה.ההימור שלי אתה תכחד מהר יותר.', 'createDate': '23:06 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 23:06:21', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45957439, 'fatherId': 45957194, 'writer': 'אמר', 'content': 'הלוואי במהרה בימינו ', 'createDate': '23:18 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 23:18:44', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}]}, {'id': 45957163, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'לשפוט ועוד לשפוט', 'content': 'במקום לדבר שטויות כאן אולי תנסו להמציא דרך להפחית את פחיטת גזי החממה כי זה אניתי גם כן בדיוק כמו הקורונה . אל תזלזלו תנסו לחשוב על איך להציל אותם ואותנו בעתיד הקרוב', 'createDate': '22:55 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:55:08', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': [{'id': 45965186, 'fatherId': 45957163, 'writer': 'נו', 'content': 'הפסקתי לאכול חומוס.', 'createDate': '15:21 23.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-23 15:21:32', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}]}, {'id': 45957128, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'רון', 'content': 'מעניין את הביצה השמאלית \nאפשר לחשוב שכל יום אני רואה דוב קוטב , \nיותר חרבנה שהממשלה רוכשת ב100 מיליון שקל רכבים חדשים לצי הממשלתי .', 'createDate': '22:52 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:52:49', 'positive': 1, 'negative': 3, 'children': [{'id': 45957187, 'fatherId': 45957128, 'writer': 'לשפוט ועוד לשפוט', 'content': 'אז תחשוב פעמיים לפני כי הביצה הימנית  שלך אולי כן יחשוב על איך לשרוד, כי כסף ורכבים ממשלתיים הם ממש לא קשורים להצלת העולם ', 'createDate': '22:57 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:57:28', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}]}, {'id': 45956967, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'יואב', 'content': 'העולם יכחד לפני', 'createDate': '22:36 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:36:11', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 1, 'children': []}, {'id': 45956939, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'God', 'content': 'iT’s OK, U Ain’T GoNna maKe iT ThaT FaR AnYWaY... HaVe FuN... iT Won’T TakE LonG.', 'createDate': '22:33 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:33:42', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 2, 'children': []}, {'id': 45956698, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'המשקיף', 'content': 'בקצב כזה, ספק רב אם בני האדם ישרדו עד 2100. ודובי הקוטב - סיכוי טוב שישארו הרבה אחרינו.', 'createDate': '22:11 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:11:26', 'positive': 4, 'negative': 1, 'children': [{'id': 45957092, 'fatherId': 45956698, 'writer': 'אבנר', 'content': 'מצויין. להם מגיע!', 'createDate': '22:49 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:49:50', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}]}, {'id': 45955752, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'א', 'content': 'לא צריך לעשות הרבה. פשוט להעביר אוכלוסיות של דובי קוטב לקוטב הדרומי. ', 'createDate': '20:37 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 20:37:41', 'positive': 3, 'negative': 2, 'children': [{'id': 45956703, 'fatherId': 45955752, 'writer': 'ב', 'content': 'גם שם הקרחונים נמסים אם אתה לא מעודכן', 'createDate': '22:11 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:11:50', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 46011605, 'fatherId': 45955752, 'writer': 'מיכאל', 'content': 'גם חשבתי על זה, והט*פש שכתב שגם שם הקרחונים נמסים, לא מבין שהקוטב הדרומי יושב על יבשת (אנטרטיקה) ולא על ים כמו הקוטב הצפוני, חוץ מזה שהוא קר ב 20 מעלות בממוצע מהצפוני.', 'createDate': '00:12 27.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-27 00:12:08', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}]}, {'id': 45951584, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'רון', 'content': 'חבל על הדובים, הכל בגלל ביבי', 'createDate': '14:15 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 14:15:58', 'positive': 2, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45951006, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'נו', 'content': 'איזה קישקוש מטופש.', 'createDate': '13:31 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 13:31:22', 'positive': 3, 'negative': 1, 'children': []}, {'id': 45948558, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'תרגיעו', 'content': 'נמאס כבר מדובי הקוטב האכזריים שכל שנה רוצחים אלפי כלבי ים תמימים וחמודים שלא עשו להם שום דבר רע, כולל גורים חסרי ישע! לדובי הקוטב אין אויבים טבעיים (האויבים נכחדו מזמן) והם מתרבים בלי סוף. אם יפחת מספרם אז כלבי הים החמודים יוכלו סוף סוף לנשום לרווחה', 'createDate': '09:45 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 09:45:44', 'positive': 5, 'negative': 9, 'children': [{'id': 45949265, 'fatherId': 45948558, 'writer': 'אחד', 'content': 'תגובה מטומטמת של אדם מטומטם..ממי שכן נמאס זה מאנושות שמכחידה את בעלי החיים..ואם יפחת מיספרם  סוף סוף בעליי החיים יינשמו לרווחה', 'createDate': '10:50 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 10:50:43', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45957042, 'fatherId': 45948558, 'writer': 'tt', 'content': 'תגובה דבילית וגם מי שהגיב לך אידיוט.', 'createDate': '22:44 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:44:56', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}]}, {'id': 45947887, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'הבלופר מבלפור', 'content': 'מתי כבר נקבל כתבה על המוסלמים שהם בסכנת הכחדה...', 'createDate': '08:47 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 08:47:37', 'positive': 8, 'negative': 0, 'children': [{'id': 45956953, 'fatherId': 45947887, 'writer': 'J', 'content': 'עם כל העצב שטמון בתגובה שלך, היא אחת המצחיקות שקראתי מאז פרוץ המגיפה...', 'createDate': '22:35 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:35:11', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 46011614, 'fatherId': 45947887, 'writer': 'מיכאל', 'content': 'בסין מצאו שיטה', 'createDate': '00:12 27.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-27 00:12:58', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}]}, {'id': 45947590, 'fatherId': 0, 'writer': 'דובי', 'content': 'מי שלא מסתגל נכחד. קוראים לזה אבולוציה. זה לא רעיון חדש... החוקרים לא שמעו על אבולוציה?', 'createDate': '08:20 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 08:20:28', 'positive': 3, 'negative': 6, 'children': [{'id': 45947883, 'fatherId': 45947590, 'writer': 'הבלופר מבלפור', 'content': 'אתה חכם.  איזה עומק מסתתר בתגובתך. שאפו.', 'createDate': '08:47 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 08:47:11', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45948695, 'fatherId': 45947590, 'writer': 'חי בר', 'content': 'דובי צודק! הגיע זמן שהאדם יפסיק להתערב בטבע כאילו הוא אלוהים שקובע איזה מין יחיה ואיזה לא. החוקרים רק רוצים עוד ועוד כסף', 'createDate': '09:58 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 09:58:54', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45957054, 'fatherId': 45947590, 'writer': 'tt', 'content': 'הסתגלות לוקחת מאות ואלפי שנים, אנחנו עושים נזק מהר מהר ', 'createDate': '22:45 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 22:45:48', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}, {'id': 45957462, 'fatherId': 45947590, 'writer': 'האמת', 'content': 'tt - המטאור שפגע בחצי האי יוקטן עשה נזק מירבי ברגע אחד... זה מה יש, בני אדם הם חלק מהטבע והנזק שאנחנו עושים לא שונה מהנזק ששימפנזים עושים עם מקל כשהם אוכלים נמלים.... חוץ מהסקלה כמובן...', 'createDate': '23:22 22.07.20', 'c1': '2020-07-22 23:22:18', 'positive': 0, 'negative': 0, 'children': []}]}], 'total': 39, 'discussions': 24}}
```

Comment: incidentally,  you need to increment ```j``` or you're going to get an infinite loop.

Comment: When I define `j=0` and add `j += 1` within the while loop it works with the exception of getting an error because your sublist is only having 24 objects so either write `while j < len(talkbacks["data"]["list"]):` or `for j in range(len(talkbacks["data"]["list"])):`

Answer (score 0):

do it the "python way" :-) (it's called list comprehensions)

```
list_of_comments = [(comment['content'],comment['positive'],comment['negative']) for comment in talkbacks['data']['list'][:30]]
```

good luck

Comment: my goal actually is to take all the comments (includeing sub comments). I replaced the 30 with a variable of numOfComments and the error jumped again